# Any way to import individual components instead of entire set?

Tags: blueprintjs

I don't need all of the components provided in the 'core' library and was hoping to treeshake/selectively choose which components to import. I've tried a few variations and experiments based on other successes but can't seem to get this one to work.

Current:

`import { Menu } from '@blueprintjs/core';`

Ideal:

`import Menu from '@blueprintjs/core/Menu';`

Answer (score 2):

You can import specific components like this:

```
import { Menu } from "@blueprintjs/core/dist/components/menu/menu";
```

[unpkg](https://unpkg.com/@blueprintjs/core@1.17.1/dist/components/menu/) is helpful for viewing the folder structure of the published package.

Comment: Hi Adi, thanks for the reply. The solution you provided doesn't work (getting the standard can't resolve error). Any thoughts on why? Using webpack 2.x and blueprintjs 1.16

Comment: I was missing a trailing `/menu` in the path. I've updated my answer. Also, follow along at https://github.com/palantir/blueprint/issues/309 if you're interested in tree shaking.

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work:

`import { Menu } from "@blueprintjs/core/dist/components/menu/menu";`

or

`import { Toaster } from "@blueprintjs/core/dist/components/toast/toaster";`
etc

Comment: yep this is correct! you can reach into the dist directory to get the exact component you need. i'll agree the path is awkwardly long, but such is life.